# ConstraintLayout - пропорции с вьюхами и текстом

Tags: android, textview, text, android-constraintlayout

Имеется layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="small text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="small text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Отображается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сейчас все нормально, но 
если заменить
`android:text="small text"` на `android:text="big teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeext"` то вьюхи будут накладываться и перекрывать друг друга.

Задача сделать так, чтобы при маленьком тексте был "wrap content", как я собственно и показывал на скрине выше, но при большом тесте - вьюхи с текстом занимали бы максимум приблизительно 40 процентов от парента по горизонтали. Ну и также чтобы текст не переносился - я делаю `android:ellipsize="end"` и         `android:singleLine="true"`.

Вот так должно быть (отредактировано в Фотошопе для демонстрации):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть ли средства для этого в ConstraintLayout или на худой конец - тогда другими лайоутами.

Answer (score 1):

[сцепите](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains) вьюхи друг с другом, добавив к первой:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
```

ко второй:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
```

эта строчка прижмет их к краям:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
```

ширина вьюх должна быть 0dp, тогда она будет зависеть только от constraints и не будет наложений. и можно добавить маргины у каждой вьюхи.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:text="small textsmall textsmall text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="small textsmall textsmall text"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```